# zeros of x tan(x) - b

Tags: python, scipy

scipy.special has lots of functions for the zeros of Bessel functions, but I could not find a function that returns the zeros of

x cot(x) + b

where b is a given constant. This is pretty common in Laplace transform solutions. Did I miss something? Anybody know a Python implementation that computes these zeros?

Comment: I don't know of a built in, but you could roll your own using fsolve pretty easily I would think.

Comment: Not sure about existing package, but take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886882/roots-of-transcendent-equations-tanx-bx-and-x-tanx-b

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but fsolve is inconvenient as there are many roots and I need x_1, x_2, etc.
the matlab link may be useful. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: this paper https://ces.math.ncsu.edu/pdfversions/52.pdf has the solution expressed as integral, with statement that gaussian quadrature for integrals works fine. Check eqns 2.35 and 2.36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bracket-based root-finding method `brentq` performs well here. Both [`x*tan(x)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x*tan(x)%20from%200%20to%2010) and [`x*cot(x)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x*cot(x)%20from%200%20to%2010) have explicit regions of monotonicity, each containing one root (with some adjustments based on the comparison of `b` and the value of the function at the left boundary `0`). The functions pick a suitable interval [left, right] for the search.

The singularities need to be avoided, which I lazily did by adding or subtracting `1e-12`; a better solution would be to base this amount on the value of `b`, or to put `brent` in try-catch block and adjust the left and right bounds when the search fails because the interval is not bracketing.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import brentq

def xtan_root(b, n):    # returns the nth root of x*tan(x) - b, starting with n = 0
    if b >= 0:
        left = np.pi*n
        right = left + np.pi/2 - 1e-12
    else:
        right = np.pi*(n + 1)
        left = right - np.pi/2 + 1e-12
    return brentq(lambda x: x*np.tan(x) - b, left, right)

def xcot_root(b, n):    # returns the nth root of x*cot(x) - b, starting with n = 0
    if b <= 1:
        left = np.pi*n + 1e-12
        right = np.pi*(n + 1) - 1e-12
    else:
        left = np.pi*(n + 1) + 1e-12
        right = np.pi*(n + 2) - 1e-12
    return brentq(lambda x: x/np.tan(x) - b, left, right)
```

Testing:

```
print([xtan_root(4.2, k) for k in range(7)])
print([xtan_root(-4.2, k) for k in range(7)])
print([xcot_root(4.2, k) for k in range(7)])
print([xcot_root(-4.2, k) for k in range(7)])
```

Output:

```
[1.2758753927614157, 3.956797869352993, 6.83423679964421, 9.828615139392694, 12.881549851182765, 15.965206716324374, 19.066376218026804]
[2.0188718954154634, 5.64338450641679, 8.98762321307202, 12.235715130594514, 15.442408472271651, 18.6277946237861, 21.800827083037863]
[3.888498133022309, 7.3338897678859825, 10.618936065272592, 13.842583205828442, 17.03705753823714, 20.215505142368496, 23.38423148227209]
[2.589154213035516, 5.375625747913372, 8.32140029715318, 11.349993150773297, 14.420577443300068, 17.514121595194442, 20.621277153352]
```